# OpenVPN connection works fine in Linux but not Windows 8

Tags: openvpn, windows-8

I have a server set up running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and OpenVPN.

When I connect to it using my home computer running Arch Linux the VPN connection works flawlessly. I can browse websites and watch videos etc. All traffic is correctly routed over the VPN connection and when I access other websites they see my servers IP address rather than my home computers IP address as expected.

On Windows 8 on the other hand using the official OpenVPN software distribution for Windows it doesn't work the same way. I can connect to the VPN server correctly but websites still see my home computers IP address rather than the VPN servers IP address and I have no idea why that might be. I've downloaded the same client configuration file and keys for both the Linux and Windows 8 client machines but the problem remains.

I'm guessing this is somehow a server configuration problem but I have no idea what it might be. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe right-click and "Execute as Administrator"?

I had this problem at my job with some Win7 OpenVPN clients. The VPN connects but can't create the routes on windows, just because isn't running as admin.

Edit: The permanent solution to avoid asking Admin password should be add the /runas and /savecred at the OpenVPN GUI icon. It will ask once, and run as admin every run:

```
runas /user:administrator /savecred "C:\Program Files...
```